# Purpose of declaringType in BindableProperty

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

Last time when i was reviewing my code I found out that I have assigned wrong declaringType to my Custom ContentView declaring type. It was interesting because it did not affect the way this content view worked. It passed UI tests and integration tests. So my question is. What is a purpose of declaring type in BindableProperty?

```
 public partial class SomeContentView : ContentView
 {
            public static readonly BindableProperty IsSthProperty = BindableProperty.Create( 
               propertyName: nameof(IsSth),
               returnType: typeof(bool),
               declaringType: typeof(SomeContentView), <-- There were wrong assignment
               defaultValue:true);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you check the actual [DeclaringType documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty.declaringtype?view=xamarin-forms)
it says:

> **Remarks**
>
> Unused

So there is not much point about declaring it

But is required to create a new BindableProperty, even if it is pointless

Comment: Specifying a wrong DeclaringType makes the bindable property stop working. I don't know the exact reasons behind it but I am sure it fails because I've made the mistake of copy/pasting a bindable property, forgetting to change the declaring type and then debugging for hours unable to figure out the issue (there are no errors, it just does not work).